# Phonegap Hybrid App - JavaScript Redirect Makes an Absolute Positioned Element to Blink and Show The Content Behind

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css, cordova

I'm building a cordova project on iOS and Android.

I have two pages: index.html and home.html. On both of them, I have an absolute positioned div (with loading), which is ​**visible by default on both pages**. Here it is:

```
<body>
    <div id="loading_page" class="loading_page"></div>
    <section> my content </section>
</body>
```

and the following CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: #fff;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #00665d;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    -ms-touch-action: none;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
}
.loading_page {
    background: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 25;
}
section {
    position: absolute; /* tested with relative, too */
    top: 85px;
    left: 75px;
    right: 15px;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

I am on the index.html screen and when I redirect the user to another page via JavaScript `window.location.href = "home.html"`  the loading screen disappears for parts of the second, makes the backstage content of the index.html page visible and then - the redirect goes to the home.html

Any suggestions how I can get rid of the blinking issue? Happens only on iOS

Comment: Is this consistent across multiple Androids ? I had the exact same issue (with only only certain versions of Android) and my only resolution was to not absolute position any divs.

Comment: I tested that on Android v4.4.2 and 4.4.4 and works good

Answer (score 0):

If you want full control of your pages and behaviour, have them as 'page sections' within one html file: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.1/pages/

I did this to prevent the blink (flickering in my case). Also you most likely have a problem with your javascript, check your console just in case